# Creating topic models on frequency lists in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I've been using the `topicmodels` package to create LDA models in R.

```
require(tm)
require(topicmodels)

textvector <- c("this is one sentence", "this is another one",
                         "a third sentence appears") 
                         #and more, read in through a file
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(textvector)))
lda.model <- LDA(dtm, 5)
```

But the only way format it accepts documents is as actual, literal documents. I was wondering if there is a way to provide a map of frequencies

```
[word1: 4, word2: 9,  word3: 25, word5:3...]
```

This is obviously not a 'map' in R, but any data structure (data frame, table, list of vectors) representation that allows creation of topic models from word frequencies?

The reason I need this is because the topic models aren't being created on 'documents' and 'words' as such but analogous features in images, and a long-form representation needs way too much space.

Comment: I think the exact word here is a table of occurrences? But what you have tried? Don't assume that people here know what `topicmodels`, but if you add some code to your question, at least you show the usual way to create a model , I and others will help you.

Comment: @agstudy, I added sample code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Try the other topic modeling package `lda`, that will accept input in a format similar to the 'map' you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use tm's call to create the doc-term matrix.  You can create and sent in your own, so long as the "documents" are in rows and the component "words" are represented in columns.  However, you cannot simply supply frequency counts in a table, because LDA relies on knowing the what words appear in what documents!